# Broken html script - does Incapsula change the html tags positions?

Tags: caching, redis, magento2, varnish, incapsula

I am using Magento2 with fpc, varnish, redis and Incapsula, and I am facing a very strange behaviour for a broken html content. I have a phtml file containing some php followed by javascript as follows:

```
<div class="some-class">
 <!--html -->
 </div>
 <script>
 //...
$element.wrap('<div class="red"></div>');
//..
</script>
```

In a parent template (also phtml file), this file is being included using php include (yes this is how a Magento core module including it without using blocks) as:

```
<?php include 'path/to/file.phtml'; ?>
```

The problem is that on the page source I am getting the following unexpected html:

```
<div class="some-class">
<!--html -->
</div>
<script>
//...
$element.wrap('<div class="red"></script></div>');
//..broken content here due to the moved script tag
```

Notice the moved ending  tag ..

I know that this scenario can happen due to several issues, but I am suspecting Incapsula because its being used by the only environment where the issue occurs

Please suggest possible scenarios related to caching, any help or idea is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this way to echo other phtml in phtml.

```
<?php
echo $block->getLayout()
    ->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")
    ->setTemplate("Your_Module::file.phtml")
    ->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: The best practice is to have it defined and mapped to a the parent block in the layout xml, another good approach is the one you mentioned. But as I mentioned the above approach is happening in a template file overwritten from magento's module that is including in this way the other template. So again it is how a Magento module is including still not sure if this can be a reason for the moved script tag !